# readlines() error in python

Tags: python, regex, scapy

I'm new to scapy and python, and have modelled the below code on a code example from Violent Python: A Hacker's Cookbook. After running the program on my wlan0 interface I get the error AttributeError: readlines

My understanding is that readlines() converts capture into a list, then findall() is able to operate on the string line.

Can anyone help?
Cheers.

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

import optparse
import logging
import re       # provides support for regular expressions
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR) # suppresses messages which have a lower level of seriousness than error messages

from scapy.all import *

def findguest(capture):
        for line in capture.splitlines():
                IPaddr = re.findall("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}",line) # findall returns a LIST
                                                # must use ,raw

                if IPaddr:
                        print 'found IP addr '+IPaddr[0]

def main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser() # create parser object

        parser.add_option('-i', dest='interface', type='string', help='specify interface to listen on')
        (opts, args) = parser.parse_args()

# the below if-else clause is just some error handling.. if no interface is given after -i it will print the usage menu again
# conf.iface is the standard interface which will be used by the program, so we set it to whatever interface the user gives us

        if opts.interface == None:
                print parser.usage
                exit(0)
        else:
                conf.iface = opts.interface

        try:
                sniff(filter='tcp', prn=findguest, store=0)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

with the following traceback:

```
    lanix@lanix ~/python/wirelessmayhem $ sudo ./hotelguest2.py -i wlan0
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_do_summary', 'add_payload', 'add_underlayer', 'aliastypes', 'answers', 'build', 'build_done', 'build_padding', 'build_ps', 'canvas_dump', 'clone_with', 'command', 'copy', 'decode_payload_as', 'default_fields', 'default_payload_class', 'delfieldval', 'dispatch_hook', 'display', 'dissect', 'dissection_done', 'do_build', 'do_build_payload', 'do_build_ps', 'do_dissect', 'do_dissect_payload', 'do_init_fields', 'explicit', 'extract_padding', 'fields', 'fields_desc', 'fieldtype', 'firstlayer', 'fragment', 'from_hexcap', 'get_field', 'getfield_and_val', 'getfieldval', 'getlayer', 'guess_payload_class', 'hashret', 'haslayer', 'hide_defaults', 'init_fields', 'initialized', 'lastlayer', 'libnet', 'lower_bonds', 'mysummary', 'name', 'overload_fields', 'overloaded_fields', 'packetfields', 'payload', 'payload_guess', 'pdfdump', 'post_build', 'post_dissect', 'post_dissection', 'post_transforms', 'pre_dissect', 'psdump', 'remove_payload', 'remove_underlayer', 'route', 'self_build', 'sent_time', 'setfieldval', 'show', 'show2', 'show_indent', 'sprintf', 'summary', 'time', 'underlayer', 'upper_bonds']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 35, in main
    sniff(filter='tcp', prn=findguest, store=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 586, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 12, in findguest
    for line in capture.splitlines():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 176, in __getattr__
    fld,v = self.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 172, in getfield_and_val
    return self.payload.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 172, in getfield_and_val
    return self.payload.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 172, in getfield_and_val
    return self.payload.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1057, in getfield_and_val
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: splitlines
```

traceback without using splitlines()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 32, in main
    sniff(filter='tcp', prn=findguest, store=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 586, in sniff
    r = prn(p)
  File "./hotelguest2.py", line 11, in findguest
    IPaddr = re.findall("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}",capture) # findall returns a LIST
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Sorry capture is just a variable from my code.. it's just a variable passed into function findguest(). I think it's a string.

Comment: You'll have to show the code where you call `findguest`, and surrounding code, so we can find out what `capture` is.

Comment: `line` is not a `string`, otherwise `findall` wouldn't complain. Is capture a file descriptor? Try `print capture` before the for loop.

Comment: I edited your question to have a proper distinction between the actual code and the traceback; otherwise it initially looks like the traceback is part of your code.

Comment: what is your Python version?

Comment: It's odd that a supposed string would complain about missing `splitlines`. Perhaps you could also do a `print dir(capture)` just before the for loop and tell us what that results in.

Comment: @Evert have pasted the output above.
When I just run `sudo ./hotelguest2.py` I get no error, but `sudo ./hotelguest2.py -i wlan0` throws the above error.

Comment: I think the first version, without an option, doesn't do anything: that will have `if opts.interface == None:` evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Your `capture` variable is probably a `scapy.packet.Packet`, judging from the output of `dir`. Why you got `<type 'str'>`, I don't know: you may have done something wrong when printing that. To convert the `Packet` to a `str`, you can simply try `for line in str(capture).splitlines()` first, and see what that gives you. But there may be other `Packet` methods that give what you want.

Comment: Apologies, I must have somehow made an error! After changing the code I am now getting the capture type as `<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Ether'>`
One strange thing though, whenever I execute the `sudo ./hotelguest2.py -i wlan0` command it hangs for 1-3 minutes before it gives me the error.

Comment: @Evert now the script is functioning perfectly, thank you for taking the time to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines() does not convert capture into a list where capture is a string`.

It works on a file object rather.Use `capture.split("\n")` instead or `capture.splitlines()`

Comment: Well I initially had this:

`def findguest(capture):
                IPaddr = re.findall("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}",capture) # findall returns a LIST`

however received the error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`
Isn't capture a string?

Comment: use `print type(capture)` to know its type

Comment: Hmm it's a string.. so not sure why the above is failing.

Comment: Show the *full* traceback.

Comment: Have added the full traceback under my question, thanks.

Comment: Have you also updated the code in the question with `split` or `splitlines` instead of `readlines`?

Comment: No @Evert. My question is based on the snippet of code I posted in the comment, I shouldn't even have to use readlines()/split() because capture is a string and hence findall() should work.

Comment: Can we see what is the output of `print type(capture)`?

Comment: @Evert I have updated the code using splitlines() and pasted the new traceback.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton 
`<type 'str'>`

Comment: Your regular expression works if a string is given, I ran this test: `re.findall("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}",'127.0.0.1')` and it got `[127.0.0.1']` as the result. Try dropping the `for` and do the regexp directly on `capture`, as you did before, and please post the error traceback/output. Careful with the indentation.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton have done so above. It is traceback #2, thanks.